# How can I turn off the display with the Griffin Powermate in Windows?

Tags: windows, display, energy-saving, griffin-powermate

I want the display to turn off after a long press onto the Griffin Powermate. The software that Griffin provides for windows allows "opening an application"; but it cannot open the shortcut "C:\Windows\nircmd.exe monitor off" for example.

I do not wish to emulate a Keypress for the shortcut to the nircmd-Shortcut - I regard that as non-ideal because the keyboard shortcut can mess with all kinds of applications.

Comment: "but it cannot open the shortcut `C:\Windows\nircmd.exe monitor off`" Why not? What happens when you try to use that?  Have you tried putting it in a batch file and launching that?

Comment: @techie007 well, telling it to open shortcut will only open nircmd.exe without any commands. I just tried a .bat script with`nircmd.exe monitor off` and griffin powermate can in fact open scripts. ~~However the display gets turned off only for a couple of seconds. I assume it has something to do with cmd running that it gets woken up again~~

EDIT: Nevermind, that was another issue. It works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the line to launch nircmd (`C:\Windows\nircmd.exe monitor off` in your case) into a batch file, and then launch the batch file from the Powermate software. :)